# Schrodinger equation with parameters

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, asymptotics

I need to know the ground state energy $E_0$ defined by the following stationary Schrodinger equation:
$$
-\frac{a}{2}\phi''(\xi) + \left(\frac1{2a}\sinh^2(2\xi) + (2b-1)\cosh(2\xi)\right)\phi(\xi) = E_0\ \phi(\xi).
$$
Here $\xi$ is a dimensionless coordinate, $a>0$ and $b$ are dimensionless parameters. I know the answer $E_0=0$ for the $b=0$ case. I have doubts exact answers are possible for other cases. So I want to consider limiting cases. In my opinion, there are three simple cases:

$a\to +0$,

$b \to 0$,

and $b\to +\infty$.

The case $a \to +\infty$ looks nontrivial to me. I have qualitative arguments in favor of $E_0 \sim C a/\log^2(a)$ asymptotic in this case, where $C$ is an unknown constant. But that's not enough. So the question is: what is the exact asymptotic of $E_0$ in the $a\to+\infty$ limit, with $C$ multiplier expressed explicitly or as a solution to some equation?